# web.config URL rewrite syntax

Tags: web-config

I am attempting to rewrite my current URLs dynamically created by the DB to search engine friendly URLs

e.g http://mysite.co.uk/clubs/?club=AFC%20Wimbledon

would become http://mysite.co.uk/clubs/afc-wimbledon

I have the following web.config which seems to do nothing;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^clubs/?club=([A-z0-9]+)"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="clubs/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this rather empty party but I'll add this regardless due to my current research around the re-write module.  See this [rewrite reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) which is probably the best reference I've seen on the subject.

As for your question it appears you may be coming at this from the wrong angle, your 'pretty' URL would internally end up being the application readable url.  In your example, a user would enter the human readable url, and this would be 're-written' so your application can interpret it (the url with query string params).

Swap your rules and actions so you match the '/clubs/afc/' which redirects to '/clubs/club/?club={R:1}' - then test.  Note you can always install the module on your local iis and test the rules through the iis manager (if you have access to it).